# Atualizando Div de dados de um arquivo Json sem piscar a tela

Tags: javascript, html, json, atualização

Eu estou usando o script abaixo para pegar valores que estão em um arquivo Json (que está armazenado num equipamento de automação industrial ligado numa rede TCP/IP e é "tipo" um servidor web ULTRA básico) e colocá-los em Divs de uma página html baseado no ID do Div. O script está dentro desse arquivo index.html que está armazenado no meu PC que também está ligado na mesma rede.

Esse "servidor" é ULTRA limitado porque não me permite fazer nenhuma configuração especial para evitar o problema de cross-domain, não roda nada server-side e tem pouquíssima memória (30Kb). Por isso que eu tenho que rodar as páginas que pegam informação deste equipamento, no meu PC. Basicamente ele pega informações de sensores de uma planta industrial e substitui os valores do tipo ":="BD".TAG:" (do arquivo Json que está nele) em valores conhecidos.

**Script dentro da index.html**

```
<script>
    function callback(json)
    {
        document.getElementById("Nro_Ensaio").innerHTML = json.Nro_Ensaio;
        document.getElementById("SP_Pelotas1").innerHTML = json.SP_Pelotas;
        document.getElementById("SP_Pelotas2").innerHTML = json.SP_Pelotas;
        document.getElementById("PV_Pelotas1").innerHTML = json.PV_Pelotas;
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = json.Status;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.103/awp/VAR_PRENSAS/ensaio.json"></script>
```

**Ensaio.json**

```
callback({
    'Inicia': ':="ENSAIO".CMDS.LIBERA:',
    'Rearme': ':="ENSAIO".CMDS.RESET:',
    'Nro_Serie': ':="ENSAIO".Nro_Serie:',
    'Modelo': ':="ENSAIO".Modelo:',
    'Nro_Ensaio': ':="ENSAIO".Nro_Ensaio:',
    'Pronto': ':="ENSAIO".Pronto:',
    'Data': ':="ENSAIO".Data:',
    'Hora': ':="ENSAIO".Hora:',
    'SP_Pelotas': ':="ENSAIO".SP_Pelotas:',
    'PV_Pelotas': ':="ENSAIO".PV_Pelotas:',
    'Status': ':="ENSAIO".Status:'
});
```

Quando eu abro o arquivo index.html em um browser qualquer eu consigo visualizar os dados recebidos por esse equipamento, porém eu preciso que esses valores sejam atualizados a cada segundo. Eu tentei realizar a atualização da página com o código abaixo, porém os dados que recebo do equipamento ficam piscando durante a atualização da página.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(1000);">
```

***Como eu posso fazer para ler esse arquivo json a cada segundo e atualizar os dados da página index.html sem "piscar" a página durante a atualização?***

Comment: Já deu uma olhada a esta pergunta/resposta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link

Comment: Já sim @Sergio, porém devido a limitação do equipamento eu não consigo fazer isso nele.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, para não "piscar" a tela, você deve chamar o javascript várias vezes e não o `location.reload()`.

Mude a função do setTimeOut para chara o Callback e coloque a chamada do Callback no final do body.

### Exemplo

HTML

```
<body>

<script>
    function callback(json)
    {
        document.getElementById("Nro_Ensaio").innerHTML = json.Nro_Ensaio;
        document.getElementById("SP_Pelotas1").innerHTML = json.SP_Pelotas;
        document.getElementById("SP_Pelotas2").innerHTML = json.SP_Pelotas;
        document.getElementById("PV_Pelotas1").innerHTML = json.PV_Pelotas;
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = json.Status;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.103/awp/VAR_PRENSAS/ensaio.json"></script>
</body>
```

Ensaio.json

```
 setTimeout(function(){
        callback({
            'Inicia': ':="ENSAIO".CMDS.LIBERA:',
            'Rearme': ':="ENSAIO".CMDS.RESET:',
            'Nro_Serie': ':="ENSAIO".Nro_Serie:',
            'Modelo': ':="ENSAIO".Modelo:',
            'Nro_Ensaio': ':="ENSAIO".Nro_Ensaio:',
            'Pronto': ':="ENSAIO".Pronto:',
            'Data': ':="ENSAIO".Data:',
            'Hora': ':="ENSAIO".Hora:',
            'SP_Pelotas': ':="ENSAIO".SP_Pelotas:',
            'PV_Pelotas': ':="ENSAIO".PV_Pelotas:',
            'Status': ':="ENSAIO".Status:'
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Olá @anmaia, O setTimeout ficará dentro do Ensaio.json mesmo? Porque você colocou (2x) <script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.103/awp/VAR_PRENSAS/ensaio.json"></script> 
 no HTML?

Comment: @RafaelMofati copie e colei errado. Agora está corrigido.

Comment: Obrigado @anmaia, vou fazer o teste amanhã pela manhã para ver o resultado. Só estarei perto do equipamento pela manhã.

Comment: Colocar os scripts no final do `body` é um pouco antiquado, eu diria para usar um `$(document).ready` ou algo semelhante, só para deixar mais entendível mesmo.

Comment: Estou aceitando códigos prontos @Patrick. Meu conhecimento em programação pra web é bem limitado.

Comment: @Patrick pelo que entendi, ele não pode usar nada além do que já está lá. Já que ele disse que o equipamento é limitado. Imagino que ele não possa utilizar jQuery.

Comment: jQuery roda no servidor @anmaia @Patrick? Se não depender eu talvez possa usar.

Comment: @RafaelMofati a sugestão do Patrick é válida, porém, fazer da forma que ele sugeriu você deve adicionar a lib do [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) na sua página html. Como você disse que é limitado, essa é a forma de resolver seu problema com mínimo de alteração possível.

Comment: No sei caso, @RafaelMofati, sim. jQuery vai funcionar.  Basta adicionar a referência da no seu arquivo html.

Comment: eu tenho jQuery sim. Uso ele pra fazer o callback se não me engano. @anmaia

Comment: Sugestão de código com jQuery? Só temos que lembrar o cross-domain é um problemão pra mim. E como não tenho internet no local, não posso usar serviços de proxy para tratar isso. @anmaia

Comment: @RafaelMofati, sugiro que deixe da forma que está. Se isso resolve seu problema, não creio que adicionar a lib do jquery vai melhorar sua solução. Sou adepto do [KISS principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) :). Talvez o Patrick possa sugerir uma implementação com jQuery.

Comment: OK @anmaia, amanhã de manhã eu vou fazer o teste com o código que você passou. Qualquer coisa eu posto mais alguma coisa aqui. Obrigado!