# Eliminar dados sem dar refresh á pagina

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou a deixar de utilizar paginas a mais para usar funções dentro da pagina PHP. Ou seja uso PDO com um php para as functions e uso tudo na pagina sem carregar nada externo.

A minha duvida é como usar ajax neste caso. 
Quero enviar um botão de um form, mas a função está dentro da pagina.
 Passo a citar o código.

Este é um exemplo para eliminar dados:

Form enviado para este trecho

```
if (isset($_POST['deletepost'])){

   if(empty($errors) === true){
      $postiddel = $postid;

      $users->deletepost($postiddel);
      header('Location: home');
      exit();
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" name="deleteform" action="">

    <input type="text" name="postid" hidden value="<?php echo $postid; ?>">
    <li><button type="submit" name="deletepost" class="dropdownbutton">Eliminar publicação</button></li>

</form>
```

O que preciso de fazer, é executar o php que esta dentro da mesma pagina sem dar refresh á pagina.... Não sei se isto é possível, mas espero que seja, pois já estou farto de usar paginas externas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já leste esta pergunta/resposta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6634/129

Comment: Já estive a ver a maior parte dos posts do stackoverflow, mas mesmo nesse não é bem isso que procuro... Porque não é bem isso que procuro, eu procuro uma funçao ajax que envie o form sem carregar a pagina... vou adicionar algumas inlustrações para ajudar

Comment: O que pretendia era algo tipo isto mas sem pagina externa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614167/delete-record-without-refresh-page-using-php

Comment: O PHP nunca está "dentro da página". Ele monta a página, e envia o resultado pro cliente. Quando o cliente vê a página montada, o PHP já fez a parte dele (ao menos na parte que o cliente já recebeu). O máximo que você vai conseguir é executar novamente o mesmo PHP, ou um outro mecanismo, através de uma chamada por parte do cliente (seja via JS,  envio de form, ou WebSockets).

Answer (score 5):

O uso do botão de submit usando HTML vai sempre chamar o que estiver no action e recarregar a página. Um método alternativo é fazer um loop em javascript de todos os campos de entrada (inputs, selects, etc)  através de algum seletor, por exemplo um seletor jquery como $(':input) e passar os dados através do ajax. Exemplo jquery:

```
function enviarDados() {
    $.ajax({
        type: POST, url: 'http://localhost/aplicacao',
        data: $(':input')
    }).done( function( res ) {
        alert('dados enviados');
    })
}
```

vc pode colocar a chamada a esta função no botão submit sem que ele envie a página dessa forma:

```
<input type='submit' value='Enviar' onclick='enviarDados(); return false;'>
```

o 'return false' no onclick impede que o botão faça o submit real do form. Assim vc pode chamar uma função ajax que envie os dados sem que o form seja enviado.

Comment: Com jQuery não precisa nem fazer loop, tem um método `serialize` que você aplica no form e obtém os valores de todos os campos.