# Retornar cálculo para <textarea>

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma página PHP com 2 `<textarea>` forms, eu preciso de fazer uns cálculos no primeiro `<textarea>` com PHP assim que o usuário clicar no botão *submit* e retornar o resultado para o 2 `<textarea>` que está na mesma página, alguém pode-me por favor dar uma ideia que fazer isso acontecer?

Importante notar que preciso manipular o texto que é inserida no do lado do PHP, caso contrário não tenho como resolver os cálculos e os retornar corretamente no .

Eu experimentei pegar o valor por $_POST['area_1'] mas não funcionou, dá erro, como posso enviar para a página PHP o conteúdo da váriavel para a manipular?

Comment: Que tipo de cálculo você precisa fazer? É necessário envolver PHP? Se sim será necessário usar AJAX, senão pode-se fazer usando somente JavaScript.

Comment: Preciso de fazer uns cálculos matemáticos com o que o usuário inserir no primeiro textarea, depois apresentar o resultado no segundo textarea, essencialmente são somas de valores dentro de alguns loops FOR, nada de muito complicado, eu não sei trabalhar com AJAX, mas com javascript sei algumas coisas...o que você acha? P.S. os cálculos queria resolver em PHP em uma página separada, tipo o action do form do primeiro textarea envia para exemplo.php, ai os calculos são feitos e depois retorna os mesmos para o 2 textarea....dá para fazer isso?

Comment: Dá sim. É só fazer a requisição AJAX com o conteúdo da primeira textarea para o exemplo.php, pegar o retorno e exibir na segunda textarea.

Answer (score 2):

A funcionalidade que pretendes parece ser possivel fazer somente no lado do cliente (usando JavaScript). Juntei duas variantes. Podes também dar uma olhada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6634/129) para ver outras maneiras de enviar dados para o servidor.

### Via servidor:

Para enviares para o PHP podes fazer de maneiras diferentes. Para fazer como descreves precisas de uma `<form>` dentro da qual tenhas a `<textare>` **com nome**. Por exemplo:

```
<form>
<textarea name="area_1"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

No PHP podes capturar esse valor usando `$_POST['area_1']`. Depois podes passar esse valor para uma variável, fazer os cálculos que precisas e depois devolver ao lado do cliente com `echo`.

```
$texto_1 = $_POST['area_1'];
$comprimento = 'O comprimento da string foi: '.strlen($texto_1);
echo '
    <form>
    <textarea name="area_1"></textarea>
    <textarea name="area_2">'.$comprimento.'</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
    </form>
';
```

### No lado do cliente

Podes fazer cálculos no lado do JavaScript/Cliente se não precisas de passar pelo servidor. Nesse caso podes nem precisar da `<form>`.

Nesse caso para teres uma referência  dos textarea e de um botão podes fazer:

```
var area_1 = document.querySelector('[name="area_1"]');
var area_2 = document.querySelector('[name="area_2"]');
var botao = document.querySelector('button');

botao.onclick = function () {
    area_2.value = area_1.value * 3;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4v0rantz/

Comment: Sergio, eu vou tentar fazer desse modo, se eu não conseguir eu retorno aqui, se funcionar eu marco a resposta como certa, OK...Se mais alguém quiser dar algumas ideias serão bem vindas, obrigado desde já pela ajuda (Y)

Comment: @Luis juntei também um exemplo com JavaScript (do lado do cliente)

Answer (score 2):

Em AJAX

```
   <script>

    $(document).on('click','#enviar',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { valor : $('#area_1').html() },
            url: "calcular.php",
            success: function(resposta){
                $("#area_2").html(resposta);
            }
        });
    });

    </script>

    <textarea id="area_1"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="ENVIAR" id="enviar"/>
    <textarea id="area_2"></textarea>
```

Só fazer o arquivo `calcular.php` que retornará o valor para a segunda `textarea`