# Exibição de dados dinâmico com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo um site, em que tenho vários produtos, por exemplo e um botão para cada um deles.

Quando clico no botão, abre um modal(Bootstrap).

Mas, quero gerar o conteudo desse modal, ou o modal inteiro mesmo dinamicamente com uma function no PHP

Por exemplo, um produto com os dados

```
Nome: Carro,
Valor: 3,000.
```

Ai eu envio as informações pra função:

```
gerarmodal($nome, $valor);
```

E ela me retorna o modal, ou o conteudo dela, com os valores da variáveis em seus devidos lugares.

"Você está comprando um Carro, pelo valor de 3,000 reais."

Sei que é necessário utilizar javascript junto com o php, pra solicitar os dados sem refresh. Já tentei mas não consigo chegar a uma lógica pra fazer isso funcionar.

Como eu poderia fazer isso e exibir o modal em minha página?

Comment: Olá, seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Acredito que não dê para fazer isso usando PHP, já que ele roda dentro do servidor. Só se você chamar uma página .php dentro do modal com iframe, ou chamar dentro de uma div sobreposta sobre o restante da página (modal) ou qualquer coisa parecida. Mas acredito que seja mais fácil de ser resolvido utilizando requisições em Ajax.

Comment: Sim. Esqueci de mencionar que javascript seria necessário, juntamente com o PHP.
Sabe como posso fazer?

Comment: Pesquisa sobre AJAX, ai bota um listener no botao que executa o AJAX e poe os dados no modal.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6626/129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem simples na verdade trabalhar com a combinação de html,ajax e php para fazer requisições, veja no exemplo abaixo:

1 coisa a se fazer é colocar um campo dentro da modal aonde vai receber esta informação, no meu caso eu usei uma div chamada conteudo:

```
 <div id="conteudo"></div>
```

2 você já possui um botão que ao clicar abre a modal, então além de abrir a modal você deve chamar um ajax que ira enviar informações para o php, criei uma funcao que busca carros informando o mínimo e o máximo do valor de cada um:

```
 $("#botao").click(function(){ // no click do botao que abre a modal faça
            buscaCarro(3000,15000);
     });

function buscaCarro(min, max) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'arquivo.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: 'acao=carro' + '&min=' + min + '&max=' + max,
      success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
         // resposta do php
        $("#conteudo").append(data); // colocando o conteudo na modal
 // dependendo do conteudo pode ser html(),text()...

      },
      error: function (data) {
         alert(data.responseText);
      }
   });
}
```

O  Ajax acessa o arquivo php e faz a seguinte acao:

```
 if($_REQUEST['acao'] === "carro"):
      $output = buscaCarro($_REQUEST['min'],$_REQUEST['max']);
 endif;

 echo json_encode($output);
```

isto é um exemplo básico, aconselho você pegar uma apostila básica: [Apostilas - Ajax Php](http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/apostilas/210/ajax)

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado!
Já sei o necessário. O que tava me fugindo mesmo era a lógica.
Consegui fazer funcionar aqui \Õ/

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, vamos lá, penso que o caminho seja o seguinte:

Um arquivo PHP que retornará as informações de um produto, onde, tal arquivo receberá o ID do produto, por exemplo.

Um pouco de JavaScript (e jQuery) que fará a requisição no arquivo PHP e, após receber os dados, incluirá tais valores no modal.

Vamos lá:

consulta.php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

// faça sua query aqui e adicione em $dadosRetornados

echo json_encode($dadosRetornados);
```

funcoes.js

Agora você deve fazer um função que receba o ID do produto e usa-lo na requisição que fará a consulta. Algo assim: (idProduto será o valor parametrizado)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "consulta.php",
    data: { id: idProduto },
    success: function (resposta) {
        var dados = JSON.parse(resposta);
        $('#conteudoModal').html('Produto: ' + dados.nome + 'Valor: ' + dados.valor);
}

});
```

Acredito que essa seja a solução que você procura, basta então alterar seu HTML e adicionar a função que fará a chamada do modal.