# problema com response.redirect

Tags: javascript, asp

O response.redirect está fazendo a minha msg javascript ser anulada, como faço pra rodar o redirecit e fazer a mensagem aparecer ?

```
if request("action2") = "alteracliente" then
    sql3 = "update clientes set nome_cliente ='"&request("nome2")&"',descricao_cliente='"&request("descricao2")&"' where id_cliente="&request("id3")
    set objInsert = conn.Execute(sql3)
    Response.Redirect "cadastro_cliente.asp"
    Response.Write "<script>alert('Cliente alterado')</script>"
end if
```

Código que abre a janela de dialogo

```
<%if request("id3") > 0 then%>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog();
    });
</script>
<%end if%>

<%if request("id3") > 0 then
    sql4 = "Select * from atendentes where id_atendente="&request("id3")
    set objetodelistagem2 = conn.Execute(sql4)%>

    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Editar atendente">
        <form action="" method="post" style="margin:20px 0px 20px 20px;" style="display:none;">
            Nome: <input type="text" name="nome2" value="<%=objetodelistagem2("nome_atendente")%>" />
            Àrea de atuação: <input type="text" name="descricao2" value="<%=objetodelistagem2("descricao_atendente")%>" /><br/>
            <input name="action2" type="hidden" value="alteracliente" />
            <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin:20px 20px 0px 45px"/>

        </form>
    </div>
<%end if%>
```

Comment: O redirect faz... redirect. Não podes fazer o redirect no lado do cliente depois de mostrar a mesagem de sucesso? ou mostrar a mensagem  em `cadastro_cliente.asp`?

Comment: cadastro_cliente.asp é a mesma página deste código... você está falando pra eu criar uma nova página, só com a mensagem, e dar redirect para ela ? mas depois como eu volto pra página que cadastro ?

Comment: Se é a mesma página nåo entendo a razão do redirect?

Comment: é por que eu tenho uma janela de dialogo com um formulário dentro, só que quando o cliente realiza a operação de editar a janela não desaparece, ai eu dei um redirect pra ela sumir, logo após a ação de editar, entendeu ?

Comment: Ok, mas nesse caso podes tu fazer um `setTimeout` para a janela fechar passados x segundos. É isso que queres? podes mostrar o código com que abres a janela?

Comment: eu quero que a janela feche logo após o formulário ser submetido, como faço pra adicionar mais código a pergunta ?

Comment: Podes carregar no botão [edit] junto de `javascript` e`asp`. O aqui -> [edit]

Comment: Amigo acho que você precisa entender a diferença de cliente-side e server-side.

Comment: @user8465 acho que devias ler esta resposta e usar a solução ajax: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link/6634#6634 Assim não precisas de carregar de novo a página e podes ir buscar a informação para o modal/dialog via ajax. Percebes o que quero dizer?

Answer (score 1):

O `response.redirect` está ocorrendo primeiro, simplesmente porque ele vem primeiro no código - basicamente, o ASP ignora tudo que vem depois do redirecionamento.

Você pode deixar o javascript lidar com isso:

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Cliente alterado'); window.location.href='./cadastro_cliente.asp';</script>")
```