# Passagem de parâmetros para uma função jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou tendo dificuldade em passar dois parâmetros para um função jquery, onde irei receber o local onde cliquei, e o local onde será trocado o conteúdo. O motivo pelo qual eu necessito disto, é para fazer uma função padrão onde quando eu quero alterar este campo para outras paginas é só passar o local que validará o clique. Meu código é o seguinte.

```
function fnc_conteudo(click, troca){
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $("a.click").click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var href = $(this).attr('href');
                  $(".troca").load(this.href);
                });
            });
}
```

E a chamada para o código é:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $('document').ready(function(){ fnc_conteudo(menu, row); }); </script>
```

Para explicar melhor, faço uma requisição para abrir uma pagina de cadastro de usuário, logo apos será exibido um botão "+", onde eu dou a possibilidade de cadastrar novos usuários, porem eu preciso que quando o camarada clicar no +, ele não abra outra pagina e sim no mesmo local abra está pagina. Depois preciso também dentro desta nova pagina, quando ele clica em salva, eu mande este arquivo via jquery para o banco.

listarUsuario.php

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>         <style>                label{                 display: block;             }             .window{                 display:none;                 width:200px;                 height:300px;                 position:absolute;                 left:0;                 top:0;                 background:#FFF;                 z-index:9900;                 padding:10px;                 border-radius:10px;             }             #mascara{                 display:none;                 position:absolute;                 left:0;                 top:0;                 z-index:9000;                 background-color:#000;             }             .fechar{display:block; text-align:right;}         </style>

<div class = "conteudo">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div align="left" id="inserir">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                          <a href="#janela1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Inserir</a>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                                <!-- Listar cargos -->
                <legend>Relação de Cargos</legend>
                <?php include "listaUsuario2.php";?>

                </div>
                <!-- Fim listar cargos -->

</div> <!-- FECHA CONTEUDO -->


<div class="window" id="janela1">
   <a href="#" class="fechar">X Fechar</a>
       <h4>Cadastro de usuario</h4>                 
    <form id="cadUsuario" action="" method="post">                     
       <label>Nome:</label><input type="text" name="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR" id="TXT_NOMEX_USUAR" />                     
       <label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL" id="TXT_ENDER_EMAIL" />                     
       <label>Senha:</label> <input type="text" name="TXT_SENHA_USUAR" id="TXT_SENHA_USUAR" />                     
       <br/><br/>                     <input type="button" value="Salvar" id="salvar" />                 
   </form>             
       </div>             
            <div id="mascara"></div>         
       </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function() {         /// Quando usuário clicar em salvar será feito todos os passo abaixo         
        $('#salvar').click(function() {             
            var dados = $('#cadUsuario').serialize();             
            $.ajax({                 
                type: 'POST',                 
                dataType: 'json',                 
                url: 'salvar.php',                 
                async: true,                 
                data: dados,                 
                success: function(response) {                     
                    location.reload();                 
                }             
            });             
            return false;         
        }); 

        //// aqui é o script para abrir o nosso pequeno modal         
        $("a[rel=modal]").click(function(ev) {             
            ev.preventDefault();             
            var id = $(this).attr("href");             
            var alturaTela = $(document).height();             
            var larguraTela = $(window).width();             //colocando o fundo preto             
            $('#mascara').css({'width': larguraTela, 'height': alturaTela});             
            $('#mascara').fadeIn(1000);             
            $('#mascara').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);             
            var left = ($(window).width() / 2) - ($(id).width() / 2);             
            var top = ($(window).height() / 2) - ($(id).height() / 2);             
            $(id).css({'top': top, 'left': left});             
            $(id).show();         });         
        $("#mascara").click(function() {             
            $(this).hide();             
            $(".window").hide();         
        });         
        $('.fechar').click(function(ev) {             
            ev.preventDefault();             
            $("#mascara").hide();             
            $(".window").hide();         
        });     
    }); 
</script>
```

principal.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../estilos/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../estilos/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Timeline CSS -->
    <link href="../estilos/css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../estilos/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="../estilos/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../estilos/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/principal00.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript"> $('document').ready(function(){ fnc_conteudo(); }); </script>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>John Smith</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>Yesterday</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eleifend...</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>Read All Messages</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-messages -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-tasks">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 1</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">40% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">40% Complete (success)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 2</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">20% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 3</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">60% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">60% Complete (warning)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>Task 4</strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right text-muted">80% Complete</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                            <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Tasks</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-tasks -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="sidebar-search">
                            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Cadastros<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="listaUsuario.php" class="menu">Usúarios</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row" id="middle">
                    AQUI VEM O CONTEUDO DO MEIO


            </div
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../estilos/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../estilos/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../estilos/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="../estilos/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="../estilos/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../estilos/morris-data.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../estilos/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

principal00.js

```
function fnc_conteudo(){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("a.menu").click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var href = $(this).attr('href');
                  $("#middle").load(this.href);
                });
            });
}

function fnc_Salvar(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#salvar").click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var href = $(this).attr('href');
                  $("#middle").load(this.href);
                });
            });
}
```

Comment: Sugestão de leitura: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link/6634#6634

Comment: Não sanou minha duvida, pois aquilo que explica no post eu sei fazer, quero algo mais completo.

Comment: Vc consegue passar o código completo para que ver o que vc tem.... jquery e o seu html....

Comment: Acrescentei a parte que me pediu, porem ja estou tentando resolver de outra forma, que é tendo uma janela, onde quando eu carrego, ela vem em modo display:none porem, quando estou clicando em inserir, ela não aparece. ambos os métodos me ajudaria.