# Refresh em div sem carregar outro conteúdo

Tags: jquery, html5, asp

Bom dia pessoal!

Possuo uma página em ASP que tem basicamente 2 divs. Uma div onde há um painel que se conecta à um banco de dados e retira 3 informações de lá (uma espécie de dashboard) e uma div onde há um painel de mensagens que ficam passando (slider).

O que ocorre: essa página está atualmente com um refresh automatico por HTML (tag) e até que funciona bem! Mas, por questões de chegar uma hora que haverá maior número de mensagens neste painel, não vai dar tempo de ler todas antes da página carregar. Gostaria de ver se há alguma forma de recarregar somente o conteúdo da DIV do painel que pega os dados do banco. Vi algumas formas com JQuery, mas a maioria utiliza uma função "load" que precisa carregar um conteúdo dentro, por exemplo um html. Não haveria uma forma de fazer isso direto no documento sem qualquer load de outro arquivo?

Comment: Provavelmente Ajax + javascript resolva o seu problema...

Comment: Rodrigo dá uma olhada a esta pergunta/resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6626/129

Comment: Você precisa usar Ajax + JSON + JQuery. Seus dados devem ser dinâmicos ao ponto de consumir objetos JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem 2 modos de se fazer isso.

1 - Através de **Ajax** (pode ser com jQuery ou não) considerando esta a melhor opção

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'nome-da-pagina.asp',
    type: 'GET', // Tb pode ser post
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert('Dados carregados com sucess!');
        $('#id-do-div-para-update').html(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Falha carregando os dados!');
    }
});
</script>
```

Documentação do método em jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

2 - Através de **iframe** (não é elegante, mas também funciona)

```
<iframe src="nome-da-pagina.asp" frameborders="0" width="100%" height="400"></iframe>
```

Comment: Gildonei, muito obrigado pelo seu feedback e explicação. Só uma duvida: ali onde tem "url", como posso fazer? Porque por exemplo, é uma página apenas que tenho, neste caso uma página chamada "painel.asp", todo conteúdo está nessa página e nenhum conteúdo é retirado de outra página, no entanto, somente a DIV que aqui chamo de "dashboard" precisa ser atualizada a todo momento. Já a DIV "mensagens" deve permanecer rodando (slider) sem ser atualizada de tempos em tempos.

Comment: @RodrigoBRF Ali onde tem url:, vc vai substituir o 'nome-da-pagina.asp' por 'painel.asp'. Lembrando que painel.asp deve conter apenas o conteúdo que deverá ser carregado, sem layout ou formatações, apenas o texto/imagens que devem aparecer.

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso aqui, por exemplo, esse painel faz uma conexão com um DB para puxar alguns dados. Funcionaria?

Comment: Sim, funciona normalmente, continua sendo uma página asp normal, você pode fazer tudo normalmente nela, mas considere que ela deve mostrar apenas o conteúdo, pq se vc colocar layout, vai abrir uma página com layout dentro da div, entendeu?

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!!