# Javascript + Ajax não está retornando o esperado

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Estou tentando enviar os dados desta página para o servidor, porém o Js não retorna a variável Mensagem...

[Link](http://linxb2c072.blob.core.windows.net/072-001-prd/geral/linxshop/templates/form.html)

Conheço pouco de JS e gostaria de saber de alguma forma de chamar a variável assim que o servidor receber os dados.

Comment: Olá Tonielto, inclua a maior quantidade possível e relevante de código a sua pergunta, somente assim podemos te ajudar.

Comment: Tira a função do botão e coloca na tag `form` no evento `<form onsubmit="EnviarNewsLetter();return false;">`. Se não der certo, faça como o Gerep disse, adicione o código onde está o problema para podermos identificar melhor.

Comment: Kadu, ele só retorna a mensagem pelo console do browser, no caso eu gostaria que a mensagem fosse transmitida através de um pop-up ou que o  a parte de baixo do JS funcionasse.

O código está no link, está hospedado no servidor.

Comment: Dá uma olhada a esta pergunta/resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6626/129 Entretanto podes explicar aqui se queres enviar o nome e mail também via AJAX ou se queres fazer o submit da form?

Comment: O que pretendo é enviar o "Nome" e "e-mail" para o Banco de dados, no código do link isso acontece como pode ver, porém ele não retorna nenhuma mensagem de "Obrigado por se cadastrar"... (Mensagem que está declarada na var Mensagem="..."

Comment: Cara, você tem acesso a URL do site em .aspx ? Seu botão está com `submit`. Troque por `button`, se não ele automaticamente vai redirecionar seu site para ele mesmo e você não vai ver o retorno da função. Agora... o que tem nessa URL em .aspx ? Tentei aqui, mas não deixou acessar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Habilite o CORS do lado do servidor... 
(http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Se você adicionar um error em seu ajax, vai perceber que ele cai lá.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  strUrl,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
        if (data == "Realizado com sucesso.")
        {
            var Mensagem = "Obrigado por se cadastrar na BILLABONG!";

            $("#divNewsLetterContainer").html("");
            $("#divNewsLetterContainer").append("<span class='spnMensagemNewletter'>" + Mensagem + "</span>");
        }
        else
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('Ocorreu um erro, olhe o console');
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Adicione uma action no seu form:

```
   <form action="javascript:void(0);" id="divNewsLetterContainer" class="newsletter" onsubmit="EnviarNewsLetter();">
        <input type="text" class="fitext" name="nome" id="nome" size="20" value="" placeholder="name" required="">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="20" value="" placeholder="name@email.com" required="">
        <input type="submit" id="btw-ok" value="assinar" class="btw-ok">
   </form>
```

Comment: Não tenho acesso para Habilitar o Cors no servidor.

Eu notei que o erro acontece, neste caso especifico, o acesso é limitado quando o assunto é servidor. De forma que estou enviando somente os dados para o banco e gostaria de exibir uma tela em espécie de pop-up para o usuário.

Comment: Então eu te aconselho a usar uma linguagem server-side (asp.net, java, php) para fazer isso. Nesse caso o seu javascript vai chamar uma função no próprio dominio, evitando o cross domain e a linguagem faz a requisição para o servidor externo.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que seu problema está nas variáveis:

```
var strNome = $("#nome").attr("value");
var strEmail = $("#email").attr("value");
```

Troque por:

```
var strNome = $("#nome").val();
var strEmail = $("#email").val();
```

Do jeito que está, eles estão sendo enviadas "vazias", e por isso não retorna nada no Ajax.

Mude também o seu `form`, adicionando um `onsubmit`, desta forma:

```
<form id="divNewsLetterContainer" class="newsletter" onsubmit="return EnviarNewsLetter()">
     <input type="text" class="fitext" name="nome" id="nome" size="20" value="" placeholder="name" required/>
     <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="20" value="" placeholder="name@email.com" required/>
     <input type="submit" id="btw-ok" value="assinar" class="btw-ok">
</form>
```

E no script, adicione `return false;` após o Ajax (isso evita que a página seja recarregada):

```
$.ajax({
...
});
return false;
```

Outra coisa... onde tem :

```
if (data == "Realizado com sucesso."){
...
}
```

Talvez seja melhor usar:

```
if (data.indexOf("Realizado com sucesso.") != -1){
...
}
```

A não ser que o retorno da variável `data` seja uma string EXATAMENTE igual a "Realizado com sucesso." (sem tags HTML etc).