# Sistema de comentários sem recarregar página jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom, eu tenho um sistema de comentário, onde eu tenho uma dúvida. Queria saber, como eu posso fazer com que ao alguém enviar o comentário, ele apareça encima sem ter que recarregar a página. Sei que tem jquery no meio, alguém pode me auxiliar?

HTML:

```
<div id="comentarios">
<div class="comentario">
<div class="nome"><?php echo $session; ?></div>
<div class="texto"><?php echo $comentario; ?></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Então, um amigo meu deu uma ideia, mas não me ajudou, ele disse que eu tenho que usar um ajax para que envie para um arquivo php e que esse arquivo envie para uma função chamada append.

Comment: Quanto mais detalhes der do seu sistema, melhor e mais fácil ajudar. Pode [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar mais informação. Também pode consultar o pequeno guia [ask] para fazer um *upgrade* na pergunta.

Comment: Acredito que isto já responda a pergunta [Como criar um site sem recarregar a cada clique num link?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link)