# Chamar função PHP no jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou iniciando meus estudos de PHP e tenho de fazer um formulário de cadastro, porem, é muito ruim fazer validação de dados via PHP, então estou usando jQuery para isso.

Porém, preciso chamar a função PHP dentro do jQuery para apenas pegar dados que já passaram pela validação. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link/6634#6634

Comment: Esqueça disso _é muito ruim fazer validação via PHP_. Validação front-end depende do usuário. Já a validação do PHP não é suscetível a falhas. Se o usuário desabilitar o javascript ou fazer com que sua função de validação sempre retorne true, acabou sua validação.

Answer (score 4):

Requisição via AJAX com jQuery.

Estamos acessando um arquivo  `http://exemplo.com/funcoes.php`, supondo que ele esteja no mesmo diretorio, é possivel acessar links. Um exemplo bem simples, este é o arquivo HTML:

```
   <script>
      $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
              event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                    url : 'funcoes.php',//url para acessar o arquivo
                    data: {id : 10},//parametros para a funcao
                    type : 'post',//PROTOCOLO DE ENVIO PODE SER GET/POST
                    dataType : 'json',//TIPO DO RETORNO JSON/TEXTO 
                    success : function(data){//DATA É O VALOR RETORNADO
                        alert(data.valor);//VALOR INDICE DO ARRAY/JSON
                    },
        });

});

</script>
```

**e o arquivo `funcoes.php`**

```
<?php
    //funcao retornando um json
    function teste(){
      echo json_encode(array('valor' => $_POST['id']));
    }

    //executando a funcao
    teste();
?>
```