# Como fazer um XMLHTTPRequest para enviar valores para a propria página?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

**O que eu tenho:**
Eu criei vários botões atraves do PHP e para os distinguir usei a variável `$botoes_criados`.

Então eu tenho o valor da variável `$botoes_criados` em PHP que é passada para um botão da seguinte forma:

```
echo("<li><a href='#'  onclick='pagination($botoes_criados)'>$botoes_criados</a></li>");
```

De seguida eu fiz um javascript para receber atraves da função `pagination()`   recebe a variável `$botoes_criados` através do parâmetro.

**O que eu pretendo fazer:**
Pretendo passar o valor dessa variável para o PHP de volta para assim saber que botão foi clicado.

**O que eu tentei fazer:**

```
  <script>
            function pagination(botao)
            {
              alert(window.location.href );
              var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhttp.open("GET", window.location.href, true);
              xhttp.send("b=".botao);            
            }
   </script>
```

No PHP tenho o seguinte código para tentar receber o valor da variável

```
Echo($_GET['b']);
```

**Resumindo:** Tudo o que eu quero é fazer um XMLHTTPrequest para a propria pagina para que possa recolher a informacão dessa variavel.
Caso não entenda a minha pergunta comente que eu edito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar `<a href='#'  onclick='pagination($botoes_criados)'>$botoes_criados</a>` para fazer a página recarregar [como sugeriste na resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90240/129) não faz muito sentido.

Há [uma resposta que pode ser útil ler](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6634/129). No teu caso tens duas opções a meu ver:

- recarregar a página completamente
- usar ajax para ir buscar novo conteúdo para não recarregar a página

Na tua resposta usas a primeira opção. Nesse caso, se vais recarregar a página nem precisas de JavaScript, podias fazer simplesmente

```
<a href='?b=$botoes_criados'>$botoes_criados</a>
```

Se queres evitar carregar a página novamente, então ajax como referes na pergunta é a ferramenta a usar. E nesse caso envias os dados para o PHP, e ele deve retornar o novo conteúdo.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', window.location.pathname + '?b=<?php echo $botoes_criados; ?>', true);
request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Successo!
    var data = request.responseText;
  } else {
    // Deu erro

  }
};
request.send();
```

No PHP precisas de usar o get como tens na pergunta, processar e decidir o que enviar de volta.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma

```
<script>

         function pagination(botao)
         {
             window.location.href = "?b=" + botao; 
         }

</script>
```