# Como linkar uma div específica de outra página PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

tenho um site one page, onde tenho uma página externa com um menu, e o mesmo precisa linkar as DIVS da minha home (one page).
Exemplo:
Na minha página externa, ao clicar no menu Vídeos, eu irei pra Div da página One Page.

Quando tento linkar desta forma `<a href="index.php/#agency-split">Vídeo</a>`, a página one page carrega totalmente sem estilo.

Como poderia fazer esta linkagem?

Comment: Veja se te atende http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link/6634#6634

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A página carrega sem estilo por causa da barra a mais no endereço:

```
<a href="index.php/#agency-split">Vídeo</a>
                  ^----- esta barra não deveria estar aqui
```

Provavelmente você tem folhas de estilo relativas à pasta corrente. Quando o navegador tenta carregar um estilo, por exemplo `href="batatinha.css"`, ele vai na verdade tentar pegar de `index.php/batatinha.css`, pois vai entender que a pasta é `index.php`

A primeira coisa para resolver é remover a barra:

```
<a href="index.php#agency-split">Vídeo</a>
```

Ou mesmo

```
<a href="/#agency-split">Vídeo</a>
```

Este segundo caso apenas se o `index.php` for a raiz do site.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Consegui a solução com este seu post!