# Solução/alternativa para href="#"

Tags: javascript, html

Estou utilizando paginação em ajax, e a cada clique para a próxima página, o navegador volta ao topo por conta do `#` que está no href.

```
<a href="#" onclick="getitens('+(pagina-1)+', '+numitens+')">Página Anterior</a>
```

Existe algum outro caractere para o `href`, ou alguma forma de anular a ação? Eu pensei em adicionar `'\\'`, mas quando fiz, o navegador enviou para a página inicial.

Comment: Já experimentaste a dar um `return false;` no final dessa função `getitens`?

Comment: Não, o que eu acabei de tentar foi adicionar um href="javascript: void(0)" e href="javascript:;", que até então funcionaram. Será que realmente devo usar?

Comment: É exactamente o mesmo, embora diferem no tipo.

Comment: Perfeito. Agora estarei criando outra pergunta, que é relacionada a páginação, se puderem ajudar. O titulo será 'Paginação em ajax não exibe numeros, apenas anterior/proximo'.
Desde já, grato!

Comment: Para além da resposta que marquei como duplicada desta, vale a pena ver esta resposta também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6634/129

Comment: Já foi finalizada. De qualquer forma, obrigado!
Tranquilo Sergio, é que solucionei minutos antes.