# Executar função sem refresh e retornar dados da função

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Tenho a necessidade de executar uma função PHP que irá gerar um arquivo zip, gravar no banco se foi gerado e a data. E logo apos retornar o aviso que foi gerado.

No momento já tenho todas funções criadas que fazem isso. Único problema e como fazer para chamar a função sem o refresh na pagina por botão, atualizar os campo de text com a data de geração do banco, se foi gerado e o aviso de geração.

Segue abaixo a parte do html resumida para facilitar:

```
Arquivo gerado: <input type='text' readonly value=''>
Data de geração:<input type='text' readonly value=''>

Gerar arquivo:<input type="button" value="Gerar"/>
```

PHP:

```
class backup {
public function gera_arquivo() {
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ( $zip->open( 'zips/arquivo.zip', ZipArchive::OVERWRITE ) === true) {
foreach( glob('Arquivos/DE/*.pdf') as $decreto )
    $zip->addFile( $decreto, $decreto);
foreach( glob('Arquivos/PO/*.pdf') as $portaria )
    $zip->addFile( $portaria, $portaria );
foreach( glob('Arquivos/LE/*.pdf') as $lei )
    $zip->addFile( $lei, $lei );
foreach( glob('Arquivos/RE/*.pdf') as $resolucao )
    $zip->addFile( $resolucao, $resolucao );
$zip->close();

}
```

Procurei horas na internet, mais não encontrei nada que me desse um caminho, talvez a solução seja por ajax, mais não sou muito familiarizado com ajax.

Comment: A.....ja......x

Comment: [Ajax](http://webdevelopingcat.com/jquery-php-beginner-tutorial-ajax/)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar um site sem recarregar a cada clique num link?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente, terá que usar AJAX. Caso queira segue um exemplo abaixo usando JQuery pode fazer da seguinte forma.

Crie uma página separada com a função que deseja(acho que assim é mais organizado)

Chame uma página com a função AJAX e trabalhe o seguinte:

```
  $.ajax({
   url:   'arquivo_com_a_funcao.php',
   type:  'POST', // DECIDA SE USARÁ POST OU GET
   data:  {geraSenha(6, true, true, true)}, //CASO A FUNCAO RECEBA PARAMETROS, PASSE ELES AQUI
   error: function() {
         alert('Erro ao tentar ação!');
   },
   success: function(resposta) { 
         alert(resposta);
   },
   beforeSend: function() { //caso queira fazer algo entre o envio e o recebimento no server
   }
});
```

Comment: Estou adaptando o exemplo, estou avançando devagar. Dificuldade de enviar um retorno a uma caixa `text` após concluído.

Comment: Um input text? Basta no bloco do success colocar $("#id_do_input").val('valor desejado');

Comment: Deu certo. Outra duvida, como faço para pegar um dado de uma variável da Função php e retornar para o ajax?

Comment: Tem algum conhecimento pra isso?

Comment: Como essa função esta no código?

Comment: A forma mais "fácil" seria   var x = <?php echo $variavel; ?>   @WillianCoqueiro

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou a achar um caminho. Fiz muitas alterações que resultou no que eu queria. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro O que precisar, estamos a disposição :)