# Como posso manter na página um componente criado dinamicamente com jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Como manter na página um elemento criado dinamicamente com jQuery? Quando dou refresh ou volto na página, o elemento é removido.

Comment: Tens de mudar de lógica e não carregar a página toda. Um refresh limpa sempre o HTML e JavaScript.

Comment: sabe como posso fazer isso? estou começando com js/jQuery.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6626/129, é um bom começo

Comment: valeu, mas ainda não é o que procuro. estou usando append para criar cards materialize a partir do click de um botão da pagina.

Comment: E porque precisas de dar refresh à página?

Comment: é pq depois de criado, o component(card) precisa ficar salvo na pagina e ele será alimentado com informação obtidas via ajax, mas ao dar refresh e mudar de pagina e voltar, os cards somem, dai queria uma forma de manter eles. os cards podem ser criados e deletados.

Comment: Porque não enviar os dados para recriar esses "cards" por ajax também? assim quando abres a página de novo podes recriá-los

Comment: é uma ideia boa! vou tentar isso. obg.

Comment: Essa é uma das ideias (e solução habitual) que é sugerida nessa outra pergunta que referi. Assim sabes que tens o que é importante no servidor e podes recriar em milisegundos quando a página carrega ou o utilizador volta à página. Como que um "carrinho de compras" antes de estar completo.

Answer (score 0):

Usando jQuery você pode manipular o elemento quando cria a pagina, por exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#minhaDiv").html('<div id="NovaDiv"></div>');
    $("#minhaDiv").append('<div id="OutraDiv"></div>');
});
```

Usando javascript puro:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function carregarDados() {
      var divSelecionada = document.getElementById('minhaDiv');
      divSelecionada .innerHTML = '<ol><li>Lista de Exemplo</li></ol>';
   }
</script>

<body onload="carregarDados();">
    <div id="minhaDiv"></div>
</body>
```