# Fazer modificação em tempo real

Tags: jquery, html

Fiz um script simples com JQuery que altera alguns textos no `select` de *tamanhos* em uma loja:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Escolha seu tamanho...</option>
    <option value="476" price="0" data-label="p">P</option>
    <option value="473" price="0" data-label="m">M</option>
    <option value="474" price="0" data-label="g">G</option>
    <option value="475" price="0" data-label="gg">GG</option>
</select>
```

---

```
$j(function(){
    $j('option[data-label="p"]').text('P - 34');
    $j('option[data-label="m"]').text('M - 36/38');
    $j('option[data-label="g"]').text('G - 40/42');
    $j('option[data-label="gg"]').text('GG - 44');
});
```

Mas, por exemplo, quando eu escolho o tamanho no `select`, meio que os `options` se atualizam, puxando os dados do produto filho.

Ou seja, se eu marcar "M", ele vai meio que "atualizar a página" (no caso atualizar somente o `select`) e o que eu coloquei com JQuery vai sumir, e voltar só quando eu atualizar a página de novo.

Eu sou leigo ainda em JQuery, então pensei em criar um *loop*, mas meio que acho que deixaria o site lento.

Como então eu poderia verificar se o texto é igual ao que eu quero ou não, em tempo real, pra ficar sempre o que eu colocar? Com Ajax daria certo? Estou perguntando pois ainda o que sei em Ajax é pouco, então não tenho conhecimento.

Comment: _"Com Ajax daria certo?"_ - Sim. Dá uma olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6634/129 (acho mesmo que essa outra resposta resolve o teu problema)

Comment: Mas la o evento é feito quando o elemento é clicado, saberia me explicar como ficaria sem ter que clicar em nada?

Comment: Lucas `click` é um evento, neste caso o evento seria `change`.

Comment: Cara... usa Ajax mesmo, com disparo. Ai você coloca um GIF de loading para a pessoa perceber que está carregando.

Comment: Lucas a tua frase _"Ou seja, se eu marcar M, ele vai meio que "atualizar a pagina""_ sugere que a página recarrega. Mas um select só por mudar a opção não envia a página. Podes mostrar o código que faz esse envio?

Comment: @Sergio se PUDER (apenas se puder) olha essa pagina e selecionar um tamanho, verá o que estou falando, ele atualiza o select, trazendo as informações do produto filho: https://www.livreeleve.com.br/calca-legging-estampa-ametista-et0165

Comment: Dei uma olhada à página mas não encontrei o select. Já conseguiste resolver?