# Alterar dados sem refresh com jquery

Tags: jquery

Confesso que não saco muito de Jquery e por isso estou precisando de uma ajuda. Gostaria de atualizar uma informação de um produto, mas sem ter que dar refresh na página. Exemplo.:

Quando o usuário clicar no link **Foto Principal**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mudar automaticamente conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é só no Jquery e não na alteração no BD que estou fazendo com PHP/Mysql.

O código do link segue abaixo:

```
$mostrar .= "<a href='?principal=s&foto=".$jmFotos->IDFotos."&key=".$keyProdutos."' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Foto Principal</a>";
```

Comment: procure sobre o $.ajax(); no jquery, vai precisar de uma página php que vai receber os dados para registrar no BD, e uma função no ajax/jquery que envie os dados para a página php

Comment: Olá Matheus. Compreendo como funciona, porém não saco muito de jquery. Teria algum exemplo? Somente a parte do jquery.

Comment: Qual a classe que faz o botão ficar verde e ticado?

Comment: Viste [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6634/129) e as resposta lá? Tens exemplos de como fazer isso.

Comment: Olá Sérgio. Vou dar uma olhada na página informada.

Comment: Olá DvD, passo a class do bootstrap btn-success.

Answer (score 2):

Creio eu que esteja tentando enviar dados para o banco de dados sem que a página faça refresh, pois então se for isto que estou pensando de acordo com o que li na pergunta. ai vai um script para que você não tenha refresh

na sua página basta no seu form alterá-lo para `form action="" method="" class="ajax"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ajax').submit(function(){            

            var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();


            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "salvar.php", /* aqui voce insere o nome do arquivo */
                    data: dados,
                    success: function( data )
                    {
                            alert( data );
                    }
            });

            return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Olá Victor. Na verdade gostaria passar os dados via link.

Comment: basta você alterar o url, já tentou fazer isso ?

Comment: Certo. Vou tentar aqui e lhe retorno.

Comment: Ok caso contrário, vou tentar editar o código antes de sair do serviço para ajudar

Comment: qdo clico no link, ele dá refresh. Ele está nessa estrutura: $mostrar .= "<a href='editar-produtos.php?principal=s&foto=".$jmFotos->IDFotos."&key=".$keyProdutos."' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Foto Principal</a>";

Comment: no caso isto teria que estar em outro arquivo, por exemplo, eu fiz um teste rápido. E no meu index eu setei o arquivo que eu queria fazer insert no banco de dados, uma pagina chamada save.php, ele fez a "conexão" com o outro arquivo e inseriu os dados no banco de dados normalmente, se você estiver com o script e o link na mesma página talvez não funcione mesmo, e o script que criei possui Submit, ou seja, ele deve ter um botão com type submit, caso contrario não funcionará,  se isso for um botão mascarado de link, adicione type submit a ele para verificar

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.envia_imagem').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'url que recebe.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: $('.input_com_a_imagem'),
    beforeSend: function(){
      alert('enviando'):
    },
    success: function(e){
      alert('funcionou');
    }
  });
});
```

creio eu que ja funciona, basta editar os id's/classes

nao testei pq to sem ide aqui, e os links de jquery

Comment: Olá Matheus. Na verdade gostaria passar os dados via link.

Comment: mude de 'POST' para 'GET' no method do ajax, e ai na página php basta usar o $_GET['nome do campo']