# Como criar um link <a> sem dar refresh

Tags: html, link

Gostaria de criar um link com uma imagem, mas que ao clicar nela não dê refresh na página, quero que se clicar não aconteça nada, se eu coloco # a página atualiza, não quero que isso aconteça, quero que clique e nada aconteça, eu estou usando assim:

```
<a href="#" class="nada"><img src="imagens/icone-construcao.png"></a>
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?
 Não encontrei nada no Google que ajudasse.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como criar um site sem recarregar a cada clique num link?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente:

```
<a href="#!" class="nada"><img src="imagens/icone-construcao.png"></a>
```

Comment: Essa revisão está louca, Gabriel Carvalho isso msm, colocando #! o link não direciona pra nada, fica sem funcionar. Me resolveu o problema, muito obrigado!

Comment: @ClaytonFurlanetto Creio estar enganado. O #! não resolve nada, irá redirecionar para `pagina?php#!` da mesma forma que apenas "#" irá para `pagina?php#`.

Comment: Não sei se é a maneira correta, mas meu problema resolveu, testei nos navegadores mais comuns e funcionou. E pq php?

Comment: @hugocsl, existem diversas formas para se resolver o problema, uma delas é: $(".nada").on("click",function(e){ e.preventDefault(); return false; }); Porém, a solução principal não necessita de conhecimentos em js, é rápida e resolve o problema.

Answer (score 3):

Outra opção:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nada">
  <img width="200" src="https://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/PetSmart/PB1201_STORY_CARO-Authority-HealthyOutside-DOG-20160818?$PB1201$">
</a>
```

Mais sobre: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o método `preventDefault` ou `stopPropagation`. Ele serve para cancelar uma determinação ação.

A diferença entre ambos, é que `preventDefault` ele cancelará apenas o evento "daquele" elemento que "sofreu" a ação.

Já `stopPropagation`, cancelará o evento de todos os elementos filhos.

**Exemplo:**

```js
document.querySelector("#google").addEventListener("click", ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  alert("Você não será redirecionado.")
});

document.querySelector("#sites").addEventListener("click", ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  alert("Você não será redirecionado.")
});
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com.br" id="google">Google</a><br>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com" id="intagram">Instagram</a><br>

<div id="sites">
    <a href="https://fb.com">Facebook</a><br>
    <a href="https://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

Ou você também poderá remover `href` e adicionar um cursor via CSS.

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="nada"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma é usar `event.preventdefault()` na no atributo `onclick`:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();" class="nada">
    <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
</a>
```

Já que está usando classe (`.nada`) no link, pode usar o CSS para desativar o click:

```
.nada {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
.nada {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="nada">
   <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
</a>
```

> O problema do `pointer-events` é que irá desativar também outros
>   eventos do mouse, como `:hover`, por exemplo.