# Adicionar produtos sem refresh

Tags: php

Bom dia, ao adicionar um produto no carrinho toda vez que atualiza o browser ele incrementa em +1 o produto. como impedir isso? está assim o adicionar:

```
    //adiciona produto

    if(isset($_GET['acao'])){
      $id = intval($_GET['id']);
          if(!isset($_SESSION['shop'][$id])){
             $_SESSION['shop'][$id] = 1;
          }else{
             $_SESSION['shop'][$id] += 1;
          }
       }
```

Comment: Eu recomendaria você utilizar Ajax para adicionar no carrinho, pois assim você não teria problema com argumentos passado na url.

Comment: Você está falando do mesmo produto que está sendo adicionado várias vezes ou da quantidade do produto ?

Comment: Você pode adicionar tanto o produto quanto a quantidade via AJAX, a diferença é que ele vai incrementar sempre que o usuário clicar em um botão e  não quando a página for carregada. No arquivo PHP você verifica se o produto está na sessão, se sim incrementa, se não adiciona.

Comment: Após adicionar você pode redirecioná-lo para a página do carrinho sem passar o parâmetro acao, por exemplo: `header('Location: carrinho.php');`, ai quando o usuário atualizar a página, não vai entrar no if, não acrescentando uma quantidade ao carrinho, ou então, utilize ajax...

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Navegação sem refresh!](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4450/navega%c3%a7%c3%a3o-sem-refresh)

Comment: Não entendi os votos de duplicata. O que é que o Ajax tem a ver com isso? Vocês querem que a pessoa faça em ajax só pra evitar o problema?

Comment: @Bacco não é que esteja doido, mas talvez porque a pergunta carece de explicações e, além do que, o título "Sem refresh" no site tem uma penca de assunto sobre isso. É claro que dá pra resolver a situação sem usar ajax pra resolver o problema, mas "sem refresh", a solução que eu daria seria sim usando o AJAX. Se o problema é outro, então o título e a descrição da pergunta devem ser outro.

Comment: Clayton, você está usando `session_start()`?

Answer (score -2):

```php
!isset($_SESSION['shop'][$id])
```

Tenta substituir o isset por empty, assim:

```php
!empty($_SESSION['shop'][$id])
```

Você também pode usar funções do php para manipular array como `in_array`, `array_key_exists` e etc...Talvez resolva.

Comment: A solução que encontrei foi bloquear o F5 com:  <body onkeydown="return (event.keyCode == 154)">

Comment: @ClaytonCampos isso não é solução, é um remendo que não resolve o problema. Até um simples redirect é melhor que isso.

Comment: @ClaytonCampos melhor aguardar mais alternativas, pra substituir a detecção de tecla por algo mais robusto. Acho que ja vi alguma postagem aqui tratando desse problema, se eu achar eu posto o link na pergunta.