# Site com carregamento sem refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Estou querendo desenvolver um site sem recarregamento de página **mas que altere a url da página** para que os robos de busca tipo o do google consigam encontrar as páginas do meu site com mais facilidade do que com ajax. Como por exemplo esse: [**OndaSul FM**](http://www.ondasul.com.br/programacao).

Sei que esté processo pode ser feito com JavaScript. Também com o plugin [**History.js**](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js).

Alguem saberia como fazer isso?

Comment: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6626/como-criar-um-site-sem-recarregar-a-cada-clique-num-link?rq=1

Comment: Na verdade você precisa utilizar AJAX : veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4450/navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-sem-refresh

Comment: Na verdade você vai precisar usar ajax para isso segue alguns links https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4450/navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-sem-refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a chegada do html5 e seu pushState você consegue facilmente, veja o exemplo que vou citar abaixo. Qualquer duvida volte a perguntar no mais é so dar uma olhada e entender como o mesmo funciona!

```
window.history.pushState("objeto ou string", "Titulo", "/nova-url");
```

Espero ter ajudado! até a próxima.

Comment: Você poderia explicar o que devo passar onde está "objeto ou string"?

Comment: Sim, esse primeiro parâmetro é pra caso o estado da página seja alterado ( Exemplo : clicando na seta de voltar do browser ) , esse segundo você pode simplesmente ignora-lo colocando um null ou qualquer coisa, e o terceiro é a sua url, se restar qualquer duvida ou caso eu não tenha explicado corretamente por favor peça para que eu explique novamente com mais detalhes ainda.